# Android Exception handling

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

In Android I am using a service to fetch data from a web service and update the sqlite database with the fetched data.

```
    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_UPDATE_DATABASE:
            UpdateListThread thread = new UpdateListThread();
            thread.start();
            try {
                msg.replyTo.send(Message.obtain(null, MSG_UPDATE_DATABASE));
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // client is destroyed
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
```

However, If the web service returns an error, I want to throw an Exception and handle the Exception in the UI thread (which binds to this service), so I can print the Exception message on the screen.

Is this possible to do?

TIA,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended method in this case is to use either `Toast` or `Notification` objects to notify user. As I understand your program's logic correctly, you just need to pass `Exception`'s message to one of cited object's constructor and initiate it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, if I catch the exception and create a Toast, it will not show up on the screen.

    try {
        so = send(request);
    } catch (SoapFaultException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SoapFault: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's probably because you passed application context as parameter instead of activity context, but it's just my supposal, it could be wrong))). Is it possible to link to activity's context?

Comment: It worked. I had to use a Handler to post a Runnable which updated the database. This way I could use `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` to print the message on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcasts:

```
    try {
        msg.replyTo.send(Message.obtain(null, MSG_UPDATE_DATABASE));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent()
            .setAction(Constants.ACTION_SERVICE_EXCEPTION)
            .putExtra("msg", e.getMessage()));
    }
```

And then in your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected BroadcastReceiver mSyncReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
          String action = intent.getAction();

          if (action.equals(Constants.ACTION_SERVICE_EXCEPTION)) {
              Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
       }
   };

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      unregisterReceiver(mSyncReceiver);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      registerReceiver(mSyncReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION_SERVICE_EXCEPTION));
   }
}
```